# Html5 game development UI

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have been using phaser to make a simple game, however I have ran into a small problem with a creating a simple UI. I understand I can use javascript to create UI and add it into parts of html, however I am confused on how I can make it so that the UI will only be inside of the canvas/game and not just go all over the page.

Comment: Adding some code, what have you tried so far, will help us understand your problem

Comment: Could you add some code you have tried so far?

Comment: It's all about html nesting.  Make sure you have a container with position:relative and make the UI inside of it have position:absolute.